# Проблема с выводом (цикл)

Tags: c++

Можете подсказать в чем заключается моя ошибка?

**Основная задача такая**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
int i, b;
int t, j;
int x = 1;
int massive[4];

for(i=0; 5 > i; i++){
    cout << "звездочек в " << x <<" столбике:";
    cin >> massive[i];
}

i = 0;
t = 0;
b = 0;
j = 5;
for(c=0;c<5;c++){
    while(b < j){
        if(massive[i]> t){
        cout << "*";
        }
        else cout << " ";
        i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        b++;
        t++;
        cout << endl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Столбиков сколько? Пять. А чисел в массиве?

```
int massive[5];
```

Кто такие `i`, `b`, `t`, `j`? И откуда взялась `c`?

Верхняя граница внешнего цикла вывода - длина самого длинного столбика.

```js
var massiv = [3,6,1,0,2];
var h = massiv.reduce((r, e) => Math.max(r, e), 0);
for (var i = 1; i <= h; i++) {
  var line = "";
  for (var j = 0; j < massiv.length; j++) {
    line += i <= massiv[j]? "*" : " ";
  }
  console.log(line);
}
```